# Does the MixColumns step come before or after AddRoundKey in AES decryption?

Tags: encryption, aes, block-cipher

I found these images depicting the AES decryption process:

[image]
[image]

In the first image, the MixColumns step comes before the AddRoundKey step, while in the second image, the AddRoundKey will come before the MixColumns.

Which order is the correct one?

Comment: Have a look at [my answer to »Why is MixColumns omitted from the last round of AES?«](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1362/58). Both are correct, but with a different expanded key.

Comment: what do you mean by different expanded key?

Comment: Did you actually read the linked answer? You'll see that the third code block uses `InvMixColumns(ExpandedKey[i])` instead of `ExpandedKey[i]` (in the last block, this is shown as `EqExpandedKey[i]`).

Comment: @JohnPaulParreño: I'd correct my answer (I originally talked about the ShiftRows and SubBytes operation), however, I can't really say it better than that Paŭlo said in his answer that he linked to; look at that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is MixColumns omitted from the last round of AES?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1346/why-is-mixcolumns-omitted-from-the-last-round-of-aes)

Answer (score 2):

InvMixColumns is a linear operation. And because of that it follows:

```
InvMixColumn(x+RoundKey) = InvMixColumn(x) + InvMixColumn(RoundKey)
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                         "new" round key for decryption
```

So, the structure on the right is compatible with the structure on the left as long as you use different round keys. The idea behind this is to make the decryption structure look like encryption structure with just a couple of "Inv"s in there. But I'm actually not sure what the benefit of this is. For a block cipher like Anubis (which is similar to AES) it makes much more sense because each operation is an involution. The only difference between encryption and decryption for Anubis are the round keys. So, you can reuse the encryption code for decryption which is a nice property.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is answered fully, but if you check [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard), you'll see that AddRoundKey occurs 3 times in total with 1 time before and 1 time after the MixColumns operation.

However, if you are just considering the middle rounds then the MixColumns comes before

Answer (score 0):

After the AddRoundKey step, except for the last round, where it does not happen