# Missing operations in last round of DES and AES

Tags: aes, des

1. Why doesn't last round of DES have swapping?
2. Why MixColumn is not included in last round in AES?

Comment: Your second question is answered [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1346/why-is-mixcolumns-omitted-from-the-last-round-of-aes).

Comment: Your first question is answered [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10002/why-no-swapping-block-in-the-last-round-of-des).