# Where would a "half round" come from?

Tags: block-cipher

In the hierocrypt-L3 [description](https://www.cryptrec.go.jp/cryptrec_03_spec_cypherlist_files/PDF/08_02espec.pdf), the cipher takes 6, 7, or 8 rounds.  [Example source code](https://embeddedsw.net/Cipher_Reference_Home.html#HIEROCRYPT3) also seems to follow this same specification of 8 rounds for 256-bit keys.  [Wikipedia shows 8.5 rounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierocrypt) for 256-bits. I found it some other literature as well.

Where does this 1/2 round come from?

Comment: Generally rounds of a cipher are rather repetitive within the round itself as well (but with different shifts etc.). I presume it is just that, the calculations of the top half of one round. But yeah, presumptions don't make great answers.

Comment: See also: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1346/why-is-mixcolumns-omitted-from-the-last-round-of-aes and https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10002/why-no-swapping-block-in-the-last-round-of-des

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following appears in [the linked wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierocrypt) (emphasis mine):

> The Hierocrypt ciphers use a nested substitution-permutation network (SPN) structure. Each round consists of parallel applications of a transformation called the XS-box, followed by a linear diffusion operation. **The final half-round replaces the diffusion with a simple post-whitening**. The XS-box, which is shared by the two algorithms, is itself an SPN, consisting of a subkey XOR, an S-box lookup, a linear diffusion, another subkey XOR, and another S-box lookup. The diffusion operations use two MDS matrices, and there is a single 8×8-bit S-box.

So the final round operates differently, opting to replace the diffusion step with an add-key step.

It is not uncommon for block ciphers to skip the final linear diffusion operation, because it does not appear to improve security to include it. For example, [AES skips the final diffusion step also](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard#High-level_description_of_the_algorithm). But they don't refer to it as a half round.

### Salsa20

[Salsa20 (and ChaCha)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salsa20) both use a double-round, which is counted as 1 round. So [half-rounds appear again](http://blake2.net) here in this context (scroll to FAQ), due to how the rounds are structured and counted.

Comment: As a follow up, any ideas why they rounded up to 8.5?  AES you could say was 11.5.

Comment: @bdegnan It uses 8 full rounds, plus 1 half round

Comment: why not say 11.5 for AES then?  i’m just trying to get down to nuance of nomenclature.  cryptography is infuriating

Comment: It's just the convention that the designers chose. There is no universal standard on how to count these things.

Comment: And each "double round" consists of four parallel applications of a "quarter round" (though confusingly, four quarter rounds don't make two double rounds, but one).